# How can I repeatedly enumerate a buttons text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, enumerate, iconbutton, flutter-button

I want to numerate buttons automatically. In the picture there´s these icon buttons and their numerals showed like this '###'. I don't know how to numerate automatically those buttons (1, 2, 3, etc.) in a way that I don't have to do it each one manually. Here's my code:

```
Widget _lockerRow(){
    return const Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: Text('###',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),)),
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: null,
            iconSize: 100, 
            icon: Icon(Icons.sensor_door)
            ),
        ),
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 3,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: null,
            iconSize: 100, 
            icon: Icon(Icons.sensor_door)
            ),
        ),
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 3,
          child: Text('###',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),)),
        SizedBox(
          width: 100,
        ),
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: Text('###',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),)),
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: null,
            iconSize: 100,
            icon: Icon(Icons.sensor_door)
            ),
        ),
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 3,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: null,
            iconSize: 100, 
            icon: Icon(Icons.sensor_door)
            ),
        ),
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 3,
          child: Text('###',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),)),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And here's how it's showed in the app:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return _onWillPopScope();
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Menú Principal'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text('Módulo Control Lockers',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  _lockerRow(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

[image]

Help me with this issue, please.

Comment: You want the ### to just be 1, 2, 3 sequentially?  your question isn't clear.

Comment: Yes, but automatically. I reedit my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, just use [`List.generate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) which gives you an `index`.

For example:

```dart
List.generate(10, (index) {
      return Container(
        child: Text('Hello World $index'),
      );
    });
```

Or, if you desired a loop:

```dart
List<Widget> _buildEnumeratedLayout() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      widgets.add(Text("Hellow World $i"));
    }
    return widgets;
  }
```

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: _buildEnumeratedLayout(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildEnumeratedLayout() {
    return List.generate(10, (index) {
      return Container(
        child: Text('Hello World $index'),
      );
    });
  }
}
```